# JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize & Encoding

Tags: javascript, c#

I use Vietnamese in input content to an textbox like "ngày 1".
The first time I do `Javascript.Serialize` an object & put it in array, store in cookie:

```
class sampleCookie 
{
    public string tripDate;
}
```

=>I got right value string is "ngày 1".

Again, I add new record to this list with another string "ngày 2".

=> I got the first record value string is "ngÃ y 1"

I can't figure out the way to Encoding for it.
What I'm missing?

### This's my code

```
var estCookie = Request.Cookies[inputModel.SampleCookieName];
if (estCookie != null)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<ListSampleCookie>(estCookie.Value);

    // I Update string value in here
    //Put insert item to list
    serializeModel.Add(new SampleCookie
    {
        TripDate = inputModel.TripDate ,
        Memo = inputModel.Memo,
        OptionFee = inputModel.OptionFee
    });

    // Serialize data
    var sampleData = serializer.Serialize(serializeModel);

    //Update cookie value
    estCookie.Value = sampleData;
    Response.AppendCookie(estCookie);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is serializing and deserializing the array? All you have shown us in the class for `sampleCookie`. Are you serializing an array of those?

Comment: I updated my Question more clearly.